# Cannot call contract's function in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I have successfully deployed the following contract on ropsten (in order to understand reverts better):

```
 contract Test {

```
bool test1;
bool test2;

function Test() public {
    test1 = false;
    test2 = false;
}

function test() public {
    test1 = true;
    _test2();
}

function _test2() internal {
    test2 = true;
    revert();
}

function getTest1() public view returns (bool) {
    return test1;
}

function getTest2() public view returns (bool) {
    return test2;
}
```

}

```

Calling getTest1() or getTest2() works fine. However, calling test() is not working, because Remix complains about GasLimit (although I have set it to: 4440000):

`Gas required exceeds limit: 4440000.  An important gas estimation might also be the sign of a problem in the contract code. Please check loops and be sure you did not sent value to a non payable function (that's also the reason of strong gas estimation).`

What is wrong here?

Comment: How do you make that call? Via Remix or from JS using web3? Did you try adding more gas?

Comment: via injected Web3 in Remix

Comment: What happens if you add more gas?

Comment: even if I set max GasLimit I receive the same error. When using JavaScript VM I am receiving the correct error messages

Comment: Ok, what happens if you comment out `revert()` - does it run `test()` successfully then? We need to understand what exactly causes this issue - the contract looks perfectly fine for me.

Comment: yes, without revert() it is working perfectly (without exception)